# Are boolean instance variables prepended with "is" in Python?

Tags: python

Is it standard practice or convention in Python to prepend boolean instance variables with is?

For example:
"options.isVerbose"

Comment: I'd say it's a convention. Some people do it, some don't. Depends on the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixed-case is less common than underscores: `is_verbose`, and actually, the is- prefix isn't all that common.  I guess there isn't a strong convention one way or the other.